# Easiest way to display a pdf, ps or dvi file from python in linux

Tags: python, linux, pdf, wxpython

I have created an application with python and wxpython.

I would like to display a help file in pdf, ps or dvi format in GNU/Linux.

Could use the distribution pdf viewer, but not so easy when you don't know which they have.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invoke [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) against the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try also [evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/).

Comment: Yes, but evince might not be installed if the user is running KDE

Comment: The original poster did not say anything about KDE or GNOME.